# How to get an inputStream from an xml file at resources xml folder in Android

Tags: android, xml, resources, sax

Is it possible to get an InputStream (or file handler) to feed a SAX parser from an XML file stored at the Resources XML folder (instead raw Resources folder)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has been answered here. 
[Android how to get access to raw resources that i put in res folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856407/android-how-to-get-access-to-raw-resources-that-i-put-in-res-folder)

Google is your friend 'android access raw folder'

Comment: That I can get an InputStream (or file handler) from a file in /res/raw I allready knew. I was trying to get the same from a fine in /res/xml... but I think I understand that I had a missconcept. I must (to be coherent) put the xml file in res/raw folder and keep going).

Comment: Well i hope it helped. I was under the impression that if you used the getAsset() method, it essentially meant you could specify the file name and it would return it regardless of the folder it was in under the res/ folder. I did't have a chance to test that assumption though.