# How can I access raw resources in android test projects?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-activity

This is my test class:

```
public class AndroidTunerTest extends
        ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<AndroidTunerActivity> {
    [...]
}
```

But I can't access the context of my test project, I can only access the context of the Activity I want to test. So I don't know how to read the resources in the same way mentioned here:

[Android how to get access to raw resources that i put in res folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856407/android-how-to-get-access-to-raw-resources-that-i-put-in-res-folder)

I don't want to bundle all the test resources in my main app because the testing has very big files which aren't relevant for the real app.

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it...

```
this.getInstrumentation().getContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.blah_blah);
```

Took me a bit of debugging and introspecting the ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 inheritance tree.

Comment: If you don't need an Activity, you can just test with a subclass of `InstrumentationTestCase`.

Comment: If you're using the JUnit4 runner (not the case but for future visitors), use `InstrumentationRegistry.getContext().getResources...`