# Getting the Byte Array using just the image name

Tags: android, uiimageview, arrays

I am stuck in a situation. I have some set of 10 images in drawable folder. 
During my code I have just the image name. for e.g "elephant.png" and I want the **byte array** of the image( drawable ) corressponding to image name.

```
String imageName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(GroupIconAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
```

From here I get the image name and I want byte array.

Is is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Using [raw resources][1] is a better option.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2856501/1916258

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this images into your assests directory and you can access like this way

```
String url = "file:///android_asset/elephant.png";
```

Answer (score 3):

try as:

```
 // get Drawable id 
int drawableid =getResources().getIdentifier(GroupIconAdapter.mThumbIds[position], 
                       "drawable",this.getPackageName());

Drawable drawable_img = getResources().getDrawable(drawableid);  // get Drawable

Bitmap drawable_bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable_img).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream outstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
drawable_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outstream);

// get byte array here
byte[] bytearray_of_drawable = outstream.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this way should move right

First of all I should put my images in the assets folder and then making the drawbles for the same

```
String filePath="file:///android_asset/images/test.png";
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(filePath);
```

and then doing the respective streamings to make a byte array -

```
Bitmap drawable_bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream outstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
drawable_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outstream);

// get byte array here
byte[] bytearray_of_drawable = outstream.toByteArray();
```

This way we can get the image name's drawable and corresponding byte array.

Thanks