# Convert /assets/image.png to byte[]

Tags: java, android, shared-libraries

How to convert /assets/image.png to byte[] ?

I've tried like that (based on solution found on SO):

```
public void printimage(View view) {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    try {
        inputStream = assetManager.open("logo_print.png");
        byte[] bytesLogo = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

        int ret = printer.printImage(bytesLogo);

        if (ret < 0) {
            Toast(context, "printimage fail");
        }
        Toast(context, "image printed :)");

    }
    catch (IOException e){
        Log.e("message: ", e.getMessage());
        Toast(context, "printimage: convert image to Bytes fail");
    }
}
```

printImage — is declared in package like this:

```
public class Cprinter {
    public native int printImage(byte[] bytes);
}
```

But application crashes on print printimage(), error is "Native method not found: android.pt.Cprinter.printImage:([B)I"

I've converted byte to string (bytesLogo.toString()), every execution of this command returns different results: "[B@40d7c798", "[B@40d848e0", "[B@40d59ff0", & etc.

Purpose:
I have an android device with internal printer of receipts. Vendor has provided library (libfile.so) and sample source for developing own software for device. Printing Simple text is OK, but i have a troubles with printing of an Image (logo).

[Here is the vendors` tiny documentation.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8FOCM80ge-NNmlzVnJFR0dyR2c/view)

p.s:I'm newbie in Java.

Comment: Which image u want to convert...? Drawable image??

Comment: Sorry, i'm not sure. I'm using this file from /assets/ dir, and purpose is not to show in in imageview &etc., purpose is to print using native method (compiled by vendor to libfile.so)

Comment: Oh...You want to send byte[] to native method..? If your answer is Yes, then you can also do it by copying image into drawable folder.

Comment: yes, i want to use printImage(byte[] bytes)

Comment: Where did you get `android.pt.Cprinter` from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
   InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("logo_print.png");

    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int bytesRead;
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    byte file[] = output.toByteArray();
```

the byte array contains

```
1B 2A n ml mh converted data 1B 4A 00

1B 2A -- begin the block

n - printing mode
  a) Q110 support 4 kinds of printing modes,as follow：

    n=0x21: 24-point double-density;

    n=0x20: 24-point single-density;

    n=0x01: 8-point double-density;

    n=0x00: 8-point single-density；

  b) NXP only support n=0x21: 24-point double-density;

converted data

1B 4A 00 end the block and execute print (print start)
```

like wise

```
byte[0] = 0x1B;
byte[1] = 0x2A;
byte[2] = 0x21; // 24-point double-density;

and so on...
```

Comment: On executing printimage() same error occurs: 
_Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: android.pt.Cprinter.printImage:([B)I_

Comment: in the document cant directly print entire image must be divided multiple units. so u need to divide the image

Comment: thx for reading doc. any ideas how to do that? if it's means, that printing of a small image will give a positive result, i can test it right now.

Comment: i've just  tested with 4x3px jpg, same error on executing printimage().

Comment: to be honest, Arun, it's difficult to understand for me, can you please share some example for work with your solution?

Comment: as your document you need to print 1B 2A n ml mh converted data 1B 4A 00 like wise. you can print full width and height of 24 point. ex if your image has 240x240 then print first 240x24 and next 240x24 and so on

Comment: you mean, that every variable for printing must be with structure like this: "0x1B", "0x2A", "0x21" , "bytes of image (max 24 px height in 24-point double-density)", "0x1B", "0x4A", "0x00"  Right? And what means "ml mh" in your answer?

Comment: yes. but not the bytes of image and you miss the ml and mh ( mh = width/256, ml = width%256).

Comment: can i use your first method for converting to byte array, and then add to beginning ("0x1B", "0x2A", "0x21", mL mH) and end ("0x1B", "0x4A", "0x00") values ?

Comment: Also please explain me (if possible) this example from documentation: "image’s width is 169 points, 169=mL+mH*256=169+0*256=A9+0*256,so the mL  mH are A9,00;"   mL is 169 (width) - ok, but why mh is 0 ?

Comment: yeah already I said mh = width/256; ml = width%256; so if width = 169 then mh = 169/256 = 0 and ml = 169 % 256 = 169 hence mh =0 and ml = 169, also 169 is convert to hexadecimal A9

Comment: @deeplay is that the printer is b/w.

Comment: yes, it's black/white thermal printer for printing receipts, bar-codes etc.

Comment: What i understand from the doc. 24 points to 3*8 bits = 24. so each bit is a point. so you need to get the first point whether white or black if white then 0 else black 1 (may be 0 black 1 white) 24 points from left to bottom. and arrange as 3 byte. you need do this step for entire width and print. and continue unit.

Comment: and don't forget if the height is less than 24 points you need to add empty byte 0. (a column must be 3 byte).

Answer (score 4):

Copy your image into drawable folder. Then follow the steps:

```
  Drawable drawable= getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image);
```

Type cast into BitmapDrawable,

```
  Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
  ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
  byte[] buffer= stream.toByteArray();
```

You can also try below code for asset folder image:

```
  InputStream stream= null;
    try {
        stream = getAssets().open("fileName.extension");
        byte[] fileBytes=new byte[stream.available()];
        stream.read(fileBytes);
        stream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I tried your second solution, but same error occurs: _Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: android.pt.Cprinter.printImage:([B)I_

Comment: How your r specifying the parameter in native..?

Comment: in error message looks like code has been breaked off and bracket not closed  - printImage:([B)I

Comment: This issue may be there is in your in native method.

Comment: `package android.pt;

import android.util.Log;

public class Cprinter {
public native int printImage(byte[] bytes);
    static {
        try {
            Log.i("ed", "load cprinter lib");
            System.loadLibrary("cprinter");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ed", "can not load cprinter lib");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}`

Comment: you can declare the native method is same class once..and call it without using class object.

Comment: there is a lot of methods in this class (printImage(byte[] bytes)), I've only posted related one. for example there is method printString(String string) and it's works excellent.

Comment: android.pt.Cprinter.printImage() this is clearly specifying that your native method which u declared or defined is wrong. This is not prblm with converting image into byte[]. Once comment the native method calling code, then check.

Comment: Can your show me your native method implementation..?

Comment: As i understand, you want to see implementation of printImage(byte[] bytes). If yes — i unable to do that, because it's a compiled library (i haven't source code): `System.loadLibrary("cprinter")`

Comment: Who has implemented native code. And jus check the code weather the native printImage() method has jbyteArray parameter r not..

Comment: compiled library provided by device manufacturer (they are from China). and this library not specially developed for me,  it's serial production, and other customers (according to the manufacturer) are happy with this device & library.

Comment: Then what is the problm?

Comment: Problem - i can't use this feature of device (printing of image on receipt). As for your question _"check the code weather the native printImage() method has jbyteArray parameter r not"_  — i tried to send a string to see error message changing or not: _Native method not found: android.pt.Cprinter.printImage:(Ljava/lang/String;)I_

Comment: I think package or parameter of the native method is wrong. printImage() with string parameter is not found, means that method is not there in native. Mean while printImage() with byteArray is also not there.

Comment: Can you check the return type of the native method..is it int or smthng else?

Comment: Without knowing native method implementation, how could you declare it...This exception you may get b'coz of package name or smthng else.

Answer (score 4):

This works for any type of file in the asset folder

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("image.png");
byte[] fileBytes=new byte[is.available()];
is.read( fileBytes);
is.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String filePath="file:///android_asset/logo_print.png";
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(filePath);
```

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14055229/3226984).

Comment: Thx for your answer, but i'm not sure, that you correctly understood my question. As you can see printImage(byte[] bytes) is "waiting" for byte[]