# Unable to open the text file

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a text file of dictionary and I want to match words with `EditText` value. But I am getting the following error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Test/res/raw/test.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

This what I have done so far.

```
public void show(View view) throws IOException
{

    File file = new File("/Test/res/raw/test.txt");
    if (!file.exists())
    {
         helloTxt1.setText("empty");    
    }

    try 
    {  
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        int len = 0;
        byte[] data1 = new byte[1024];

        while ( -1 != (len = in.read(data1)) )
        {
            if(new String(data1, 0, len).contains(edittxt.getText().toString()))
            {
                  helloTxt1.setText("1");
            }
            else
            {
                  helloTxt1.setText("0");
            }                             
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
      {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
      }    
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this help? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856407/android-how-to-get-access-to-raw-resources-that-i-put-in-res-folder)

Comment: Do _not_ use hardcoded paths! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an input stream to open and read your file

`InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open("test.txt");` and use a `Reader`

OR

seeing as you have made a Raw folder within your res folder, call the following `getResources().openRawResources(myResourceName)` from within the activity.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is on the external storage, you should add 'READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' permission to your manifest.