# Accessing res/raw folder in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to create an application in Android. I want to access a file placed in res/raw folder, how can i specify its path while accessing it through File() constructor? And how can I display the file's content using textview?

Comment: You cannot access it with the File() constructor as it is not actually a file, but an android-unique construct.  Please see the documentation  at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use InputStream to read file content.

```
getResources().getIdentifier("raw/FILENAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION",
                             "raw", getPackageName());
```

To get it as a InputStream

```
InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(
            getResources().getIdentifier("raw/FILENAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION",
            "raw", getPackageName()));
```

**OR**

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.yourresource);
```

refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html for Providing Resources.

Comment: Yeah! I got it worked by using InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.yourresource); Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

looks like something like this

```
InputStream raw = context.getAssets().open("filename.ext");

Reader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(raw, "UTF8"));
```

taken from here: [Android how to get access to raw resources that i put in res folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856407/android-how-to-get-access-to-raw-resources-that-i-put-in-res-folder)

Another way I thought you could do it is to use getResources(), and access it via R.raw.fileName

Comment: Yeah! I got it worked by using InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.yourresource); Thank you:)