# read a file from within app folder in android

Tags: java, android, file, ioexception

I want to read a file that is saved in my `java` folder (same where my activities are) in package `com.example` so it's java-->com.example--> data.ser. However I'm getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /java/com/example/data.ser: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)` when I call

`ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("java/com/example/data.ser")));`. I tried removing the java part or just leaving the file name on its own but nothing works. I am not loading it from external/internal storage but just from within the app. How to do it? I'm using android studio. Thanks for help

Comment: There is an Android way using the `res` folder for asset files, and there is a more "bare-bones" Java way that allows access to resource files added to the JAR / APK file. Android resources: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html -- Java resources: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/retrievingResources.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files has to be stored on 'assets' or 'raw' folder, depending on what kind of file you are going to store. On 'java' you should set code class only. You can find an easy example here: 
[raw file example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856407/android-how-to-get-access-to-raw-resources-that-i-put-in-res-folder)

Comment: How you can protect file kept under assets or raw folder as it will visible through Reverse engineering.