# How to get video path to work?

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I already have my video pasted on the raw file in res but once I'm on the script the path to the video doesn't work as you can see in the image below. Any help please!! thank you whenever I try I get this message (cannot resolve symbol "copie")

[image]

```
public void videoplay(View v) { String videopath = "android.resource://com.keshagain.keshagin/"+R.raw.copie; Uri uri = Uri.parse(videopath);
public void videoplay(View v) { String videopath = "android.resource://com.keshagain.keshagin/"+R.raw.copie; Uri uri = Uri.parse(videopath);
```

"Copie" is the name of my video file that doesn't work, tried with other videos and I tried renaming it just in case but still same problem

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not post screenshots of your code. Please post actual text. Please check out this article on what StackOverflow expects https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856407/android-how-to-get-access-to-raw-resources-that-i-put-in-res-folder